# Update array order in Vue.js after DOM change

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dragula

I have a basic Vue.js object:

```
var playlist = new Vue({
    el : '#playlist',
    data : {
        entries : [
            { title : 'Oh No' },
            { title : 'Let it Out' },
            { title : 'That\'s Right' },
            { title : 'Jump on Stage' },
            { title : 'This is the Remix' }
        ]
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="playlist">
    <div v-for="entry in entries">
        {{ entry.title }}
    </div>
</div>
```

I also am using a drag and drop library (dragula) to allow users to rearrange the #playlist div.

However, after a user rearranges the playlist using dragula, this change is not reflected in Vue's `playlist.entries`, only in the DOM.

I have hooked into dragula events to determine the starting index and ending index of the moved element. **What is the correct way to go about updating the Vue object to reflect the new order?**

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cxx77kco/5/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Vue's `v-for` does not track modifications to the DOM elements it creates. So, you need to update the model when dragula notifies you of the change. Here's a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hsnvweov/

```
var playlist = new Vue({
    el : '#playlist',
    data : {
        entries : [
            { title : 'Oh No' },
            { title : 'Let it Out' },
            { title : 'That\'s Right' },
            { title : 'Jump on Stage' },
            { title : 'This is the Remix' }
        ]
    },
    ready: function() {
        var self = this;
        var from = null;
        var drake = dragula([document.querySelector('#playlist')]);

        drake.on('drag', function(element, source) {
            var index = [].indexOf.call(element.parentNode.children, element);
            console.log('drag from', index, element, source);
            from = index;
        })

        drake.on('drop', function(element, target, source, sibling) {
            var index = [].indexOf.call(element.parentNode.children, element)
            console.log('drop to', index, element, target, source, sibling);

            self.entries.splice(index, 0, self.entries.splice(from, 1)[0]);

            console.log('Vue thinks order is:', playlist.entries.map(e => e.title ).join(', ')
            );
        })
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

I created a Vue directive that does exactly this job.

It works exactly as v-for directive and add drag-and-drop capability in sync with underlying viewmodel array:

[image: example]

Syntaxe:

```
<div v-dragable-for="element in list">{{element.name}}</div>
```

Example: [fiddle1](https://jsfiddle.net/dede89/j62g58z7/), [fiddle2](https://jsfiddle.net/dede89/hqxranrd/)

Github repository: [Vue.Dragable.For](https://github.com/David-Desmaisons/Vue.Dragable.For)